# On proving that a certain sequence is Cauchy in a Hilbert space.

Tags: proof-writing, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-sequences

Suppose we have an orthogonal family $\,\phi _{n}~~, n=1,2,...,$ in a Hilbert space, and $a_{n}$ is any sequence of real scalars such that $\,\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left| a_{i}\right|^{2}\langle\phi _{i},\phi _{i}\rangle \,$ converges.

How can we prove that $\,\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}\phi _{i} \,$ is cauchy in H?

Here is my new attempt using the suggested method:

Let $\,g_{n} = \,\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\phi _{i} \,$, we must then prove that there exists  $N$ such that $\,\lVert g_{n}-g_{m}\rVert<\epsilon\,$ for every $n,m>N$.

$$\,\lVert g_{n}-g_{m}\rVert^2=\langle g_{n}-g_{m},g_{n}-g_{m}\rangle$$
assuming $n<m$:
$$\,\lVert g_{n}-g_{m}\rVert^2=\langle\, \sum_{i=n}^{m}a_{i}\phi _{i}\,,\sum_{j=n}^{m}a_{j}\phi _{j}\,\rangle=\sum_{i=n}^{m}a_{i}\langle \phi _{i},\sum_{j=n}^{m}a_{j}\phi _{j}\ \rangle  $$

$$=\sum_{i=n}^{m}a_{i}\bigg[\sum_{j=n}^{m}a_{j}\langle \phi_{i} , \phi_{j} \rangle\bigg]=\sum_{i=n}^{m}\sum_{j=n}^{m}a_{i}a_{j}\langle \phi _{i},\phi _{j} \rangle$$

Using $\,\langle \phi _{i} ,\phi _{j}\rangle = 0 \,\,$when  $i \neq j\,$, we end up with:$$\lVert g_{n}-g_{m}\rVert^2= \sum_{i=n}^{m}\left| a_{i} \right|^2\langle \phi_{i} , \phi_{i} \rangle$$

But I still can't extract the $N (\epsilon)$ when I impose:

$$\sum_{i=n}^{m}\left| a_{i} \right|^2\langle \phi_{i} , \phi_{i} \rangle < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an explicit computation instead of using inequalities.

Use orthogonality to show that $\|g_n-g_m||^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m |a_k|^{2} \langle \phi_k, \phi_k \rangle$ for $n <m$. This sum tends to $0$ by hypothesis.

Comment: I think your indices are goofed in your sum. For OP: the reason this entire approach works is built on the orthogonality which has been subtly used in this answer (see if you can find where).

Comment: @CameronWilliams, " indices are goofed " Were you referring to  the $j$ which should be an $i$ in the sum?

Comment: Sorry guys, I was in a hurry.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Would you mind indicating why the final result tends to $0$?

Comment: For any convergent series $\sum c_j$ of real numbers $\sum_{k=n}^{m} c_k \to 0$ because this sum is nothing but $s_m-s_{n-1}$ where $s_i$'s are the partial sums.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for the comment.